# Select rows that have an specific column value in all relationship data

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I have a **1 to N** relationship, with a `products` table like this:

```
  products
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
| 1  | foo  |
| 2  | bar  |
+----+------+
```

and a `options` table like this:

```
  options
+----+------------+--------+--------+
| id | product_id | option | active |
+----+------------+--------+--------+
| 10 | 1          | size   | true   |
| 11 | 1          | color  | false  |
| 12 | 2          | size   | true   |
| 13 | 2          | color  | true   |
+----+------------+--------+--------+
```

How can I get the `products` that have all of his options with `active = true`? Note that if a product has at least one option with `active = false`, then I don't want that product to be retrieved by the query.

The wanted result in this case will be product 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a sub-query to get the product_ids from the options table that are all active using Postgres' boolean aggregation `bool_and` that only returns true if all values are `true`

```
select *
from products
where id in (select product_id
             from options
             group by product_id
             having bool_and(active));
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/ILPX66228

Answer (score 1):

Use GROUP BY with  HAVING clause:

```
SELECT pr.id, pr.name
FROM products AS pr
LEFT JOIN options AS op ON ON pr.id = op.product_id
GROUP BY pr.id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN active = false THEN 1 else 0 END) <= 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use  `not exists` operator

```
select p.* from  products p
where not exists (select 1 from options where product_id = p.id and active = false)
```

This assumes `active` has `boolean` type else you would need to use single quote (i.e. `'string'`) for comparisons

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for this

```
SELECT  P.id, P.name, O.option, O.active from products P
INNER JOIN options O
ON P.id = O.product_id
WHERE active <> 'false'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you...

```
Select distinct P.name from products P 
join options O on O.id=P.id
where O.active=true
```

Comment: No, it doesn't give correct results. And `distinct` keyword is wrong here - OP wanted to get entire product record, not some name.

Comment: @arvo I think the purpose of this forum is to help people with the direction so as to end up with the solution that works. I just mentioned the product name. And solution seeker  seems pretty knowledgeable to include whatever columns he seems fit for his case

Comment: and distinct here is required as there may be same product ids in options table with all of them with active status. So when you join you wont get a duplicated product names.

Comment: Purpose of this forum is not to give wrong advice. If you cannot understand, why your query doesn't match original request, then sorry :( About `distinct` - I can see, why you proposed that, but in your solution this just hides query design issues. Sorry again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY` with a `HAVING` clause with a conditional aggregate:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name
FROM products AS p
LEFT JOIN options AS o ON ON p.id = o.product_id
GROUP BY p.id, p.name
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN active = true THEN 1 END) = COUNT(*)
```

Comment: Why this solution doesn't raise an error on the column `p.name` for not being included in an aggregate function?

Comment: @JaimeCaffarel You are right, I've edited my answer.

Comment: @JaimeCaffarel: it won't if `id` is the primary key of the table `products`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
 select * from products 
 where id not in (select product_id from options where active = false)
```